# How can I prepopulate the iCloud server?

Tags: swift, server, icloud, cloudkit

i am unable to decide on what would be the best possible way to go ahead with the task of

1. Having 50 large video files with 50 large images corresponding to those files and some related text prepopulated in iCloud so that when the user downloads the app , they have some videos already installed to watch and not have to start from scratch…
2. I am aware of how to upload text to iCloud using some code as below , but I do. not know how will I proceed with large media files, where will I store them , how will I point to them ?
3. If a user wants to play those videos, will those videos need to be downloaded to the user device ? Will this not increase the size of app significantly ? How can I avoid this ?

All in all I am totally lost as to how to deal with large size files, how to prepopulate my app with some of these files and how to add more files in future ,

Can any one please guide and point me to a plan of action I can take in this regard ...

The code I have to be able to prepare and upload some data to iCloud , but I do not know how to use them when using large media files, where will I store those files etc

```
func prepareCloudRecords(owner: String) -> [CKRecord] {
        let parentName = objectID.uriRepresentation().absoluteString
        let parentID = CKRecord.ID(recordName: parentName)
        let parent = CKRecord(recordType: "Project", recordID: parentID)
        parent["title"] = projectTitle
        parent["detail"] = projectDetail
        parent["owner"] = owner
        parent["closed"] = closed

        var records = projectItemsDefaultSorted.map { item -> CKRecord in
            let childName = item.objectID.uriRepresentation().absoluteString
            let childID = CKRecord.ID(recordName: childName)
            let child = CKRecord(recordType: "Item", recordID: childID)
            child["title"] = item.itemTitle
            child["detail"] = item.itemDetail
            child["completed"] = item.completed
            child["project"] = CKRecord.Reference(recordID: parentID, action: .deleteSelf)
            return child
        }
        records.append(parent)
        return records
    }
```

Then use it to upload to server on button click like so making a function, thanks

```
func uploadToCloud() {
        if let username = username {
            let records = project.prepareCloudRecords(owner: username)
            let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: records, recordIDsToDelete: nil)
            operation.savePolicy = .allKeys
            operation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { _, _, error in
                       updateCloudStatus()
                   }

                   cloudStatus = .checking

            CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.add(operation)
        } else {
            showingSignIn = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to use "asset" field types to store large images and videos. You can create a shared database with the initial videos and images. They will then be available to your users immediately when they launch the app. Yes, you do have to download the asset before the user can view/play it but it doesn't change the size of the app.

Comment: thanks, I will be giving it a try